# Is there any domain for testing with a certificate name mismatch?

Tags: ssl

I need a domain for testing with a  certificate name mismatch.
Is there any available?

I know there is one with a valid certificate: https://www.example.com/

Comment: You want a domain where the domain on the cert is not the one on the real domain?

Comment: `https://wrong.host.badssl.com/`

Comment: `curl --resolve` flag allows to control the DNS resolution hence map any given name to any given IP address and then connect to it; if you use a random name in the URL, then it is guaranteed the certificate coming back won't match what is in URL. So in short you shouldn't need any specific outside server misconfigured for your tests, but then it is not 100% clear what and how you are testing.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, please add it as answare along with it's root domain https://badssl.com/

Answer (score 0):

Just point a CNAME at `www.example.com.` and you're done!
Guaranteed mismatch, now and when those unit tests run again a few years down the road.

Comment: Or use the IPaddress instead -- `https://93.184.216.34/` (currently, but it could change over time)

Comment: Except the day the IP gets added in the SAN and then suddenly everything matches...